# How to publish ASP.NET Core 5 Web Site to IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I installed Visual Studio 2015 RC and created the sample Web Site project.

I published it in Visual Studio using its publishing tool to file system. The output is:

[image: Published files]

I tried to target IIS both **this folder** and **wwwroot** folder but nothing changed. I always receive an **Access is Denied** error.

Checked the permissions. They are OK. I'm always able to run my other web sites...

I want to publish it targeting **clrcore**. But I already tried to publish it using **clr** and failed there too. It is the same error.

How is the publishing process should be when I want to run a coreclr website in IIS? And I don't even know if it is possible to serve a coreclr project on IIS.

By the way there is nothing about .NET Core in application pools dialog in IIS. So I don't know what could my poor IIS do here.

Comment: Running a CoreCLR based website is definitely possible. You can bundle and publish manually by following the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29990607/149064 . Can you give more details about your error?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Sure. By the way I already asked another question about `dnu`. I can't make it work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106225/where-to-find-dnu-command-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

There are full instructions from MS:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

TL;DR 
You need to install HTTP platform Handler. Other than that, if you could get a standard MVC 5 app to work, you should be ok. The only change I needed to make was installing the plstform handler. 
Of Course, In VS I publised to a folder, then copied the contents to the Web server. The root folder to the site must point to the wwwroot and the approot will be at the same level.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, You can't host ASP.NET Core 5 Web Site on IIS, it works with self hosting only.

Comment: I believe IIS hosting is enabled via [Project "Helios"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/supplemental-to-asp-net-project-helios.aspx).