# Where to find 'dnu' command in Windows

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015 RC. I'm trying to figure out the new .NET Core thing...

Now I want to package my application and launch it.
I wanted to play with DNX Utility but can not figure out how to run it.

My command prompt still insists that there is no `dnu` command by saying: `'dnu' is not recognized`.

Searched all the entire file system but nothing found. So I don't think it is a path problem.

Do I have to install it manually? Or is it a corrupted installation problem? There is something I'm really missing out but don't have any idea what it is...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It should be in `%userprofile%\.dnx\runtimes\<runtime name>\bin`.

If it is not on the path, run `dnvm upgrade`. If `dnvm` is not recognized, install it by following the instruction on the [Home repo](https://github.com/aspnet/home/)

Comment: I found the runtime here: `%userprofile%\.dnx\runtimes\bin`

Comment: I had installed the runtime and %userprofile%\.dnx only contained dnvm. Explicitly running *dnvm upgrade* fixed it for me, thank you. It registered the x86 version of the CLR for me, so I had to subsequently run *dnvm use 1.0.0-beta6 -arch x64* and then *dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta6 -arch x64*. All working now!

Answer (score 10):

You Could try and run **dnvm upgrade** Command in your cmd.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a PATH problem. The reason why it couldn't regconise the dnu or dnx commands because it could not locate the dnu.exe, and dnx.exe... batch command files.

You can solve it either by adding manually C:\Users\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to user PATH,  or run "dnvm upgrade" in your cmd

Answer (score 0):

It could solve to run command prompt with administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

If dnvm is recognised then you can issue the following command;

`dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1`

this will ensure the clr/x86 version of DNX is added to your PATH.