# How to publish and run dnx-clr-x64 (ASP.NET 5) MVC site on shared hosting and on IIS 8.5 localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, publish, dnx

I would like to be able to run my published site on my arvixe shared hosting (if it's possible now, as it's only beta4 now), and on my dev machine's IIS 8.5.
It's a dnx-clr-x64.1.0.0-beta4 ASP.NET 5 project. (dnx451) I'm thinking of using the full .NET, not the Core. It would be also nice, NOT to publish the source code.
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 RC.
Can it be done, and can it be done from VS, without console commands?

Thanks.

Comment: You can see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973153/run-asp-net-5-mvc-6-using-net-core-on-iis

Comment: Have you published your site? 
The RTM was released and I'm asking at Arvixe if they plan to support it. Any news I'll share with you.