# How to set a startup project to update a database in a published ASP.NET5 | MVC6 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

There are two `EF7` db-contexts in a `MVC6 (beta-7)` project. First of them (let's call it `StartupContext`) is in a startup project (`MyProject.Startup`). Second (let's call it `DataContext`) is in a separate assembly (`MyProject.Data`).

There is a command in the `project.json` files of the `MyProject.Startup` and the `MyProject.Data`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
  ...
}

"commands": {
  "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  ...
}
```

I can use it for a database updating like this:

- for an updating of the `StartupContext` I run the `ef` command from a startup folder:

  `dnx ef database update`
- for an updating of the `DataContext` I run the `ef` command from a folder of the `MyProject.Data` project:

  `dnx ef database update -c DataContext -s MyProject.Startup`

It works perfectly but only from sources (from not published project). I get exception like this for an updating of the `DataContext` from a published project:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly "MyProject.Data" or one of its dependencies.

I tried various approaches:

```
dnx ef database update -c DataContext -s MyProject.Startup
dnx ef database update -c DataContext -s C:\Published\approot\packages\MyProject.Startup
dnx ef database update -c DataContext -s C:\Published\approot\packages\MyProject.Startup\1.0.0\root\
dnx ef database update -c DataContext -s C:\Published\approot\packages\MyProject.Startup\1.0.0\lib\MyProject.Startup.dll
dnx ef database update -c DataContext -s %~dp0approot\packages\MyProject.Startup
dnx ef database update -c DataContext -s %~dp0approot\packages\MyProject.Startup\1.0.0\root\
```

I also tried to copy the `MyProject.Startup.dll` to a folder with the `MyProject.Data` but unsuccessfully.

Has anybody else had a similar problem?

How can I update a database and create a migration from a published project?

Comment: Make sure that your target framework is the right one (for example, `clr` instead of `coreclr`)

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I am sure, I use the Clr framework in all my projects.

Comment: What does `dnvm list` tells you? Is the right version selected there? I found out that (in order to publish to Azure) I had to have everything lined up.

Comment: @hypercodeplace How are you creating the published project?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera there is only `dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7` And it is used as standard.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I created the published project by the Publish WIzard of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Do you have an intermediate directory where the published project is located? If so, does `dnu build` work there?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera It seems it doesn't work. My command is `@"%~dp0approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7\bin\dnx.exe" dnu build`. There is the `System.InvalidOperationException. Unable to resolve project "Release"`  exception. The intermediate directory (a folder with published solution) names  `C:\Release`.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio always uses x86 version of DNX (for now I think). You may check it in output window under 'Package Manager' pane. If you need x64 version you may need to build it on your own using `dnu restore`, `dnu build` or line up versions with VS using `dnvm use` as @LeonardoHerrera mentioned.

Comment: I note when I applied all migrations and updated database from sources directory (using a path to the battle db) project works perfectly from intermediate directory (launch it by the `dnx web` command). Therefore I think a framework doesn't affect on succfully db updating.

Comment: I've observed that there is some disconnection on the dnu commands and Visual Studio. I assume that `dnx web` also doesn't work in your published directory. Anyways, check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973153/run-asp-net-5-mvc-6-using-net-core-on-iis) on publishing x64 projects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in EF7-beta7 and should be fixed in the upcoming RC1 release of EF.

If you *need* (as in very much so) this feature before the, you could use the nightly builds of EF. (Caution: nightly builds have a lot of instability.)