# Running ASP.NET CORE (MVC 6) under IIS other then localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I setup an ASP.NET app under IIS as described here:  [Run ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) using .NET Core on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973153/run-asp-net-5-mvc-6-using-net-core-on-iis)

Everything works fine when I access the site with "http://localhost:19691/blahblah", BUT if I replace localhost with the machine's internal IP address (http://10.10.38.57:19691/blahblah), connection is refused.  Also "127.0.0.1:19691/blahblah" works fine too.  I try all this from the same machine that I have IIS on.  If I try "10.10.38.57:80" where my IIS root lives I do get the IIS welcome page.  Which is what's expected.

I disabled the firewall on the machine.  Is there some Kestrel configuration that I am missing?

Comment: When you use the IP i think IIS treats that as an external connection rather than as a connection from the same machine, so i'd say check the authentication settings, you might have something that work for internal connections but not external ones

Comment: Is your app running in a virtual directory under the Default Web Site or is it a separate web site?

Comment: it's setup as virtual directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had create hosting.json file in the root of the project and put the following in it:

`{
  "server": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  "server.urls": "http://10.10.38.57:19691/"
}`

Comment: I think that configuration API changed and now it is `urls` instead of `server.urls`

Comment: There are a few other places in the project properties debug page (and launchconfig.json) that you may need to update also.